# Programmatically detecting pages that override ctrl+f

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I've seen several sites that provide custom functionality when the "ctrl+f" hotkeys are used. For example, Google Docs or Google Sheets will have a custom find pop-up for the document, GitHub will have a custom regex search when editing code in the browser, and Codepen also has a custom search feature.

Is there any way to programmatically detect (e.g., via javascript) whether a particular site overrides ctrl+f? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Detect how? Other than just trying it?

Comment: Oh, programmatically detect via Javascript or some other means, for instance.

Comment: You'll have to find all the keypress (and similar) event listeners, then see if they `e.preventDefault()` `Ctrl`+`F`. No, I don't think you can (easily) do this.